# Replace a character in a file using a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch file scripting and need to develop a script to replace a character in a file using a batch script.

I have to replace "servername/ActionService.asmx,1"
with "servername/ActionService.asmx,0"
in file called APP.

Please let me know if there is any solution using only commands.

Answer (score 2):

You can use GNUWin32 [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
set "string=servername/ActionService.asmx,1"
FOR /f %%a IN ('echo "%string%" ^| sed "s/[0-9]/0/"') DO set "newstring=%%~a"
ECHO %newstring%
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're toggling back and forth between these two states, it might be easier to create two copies of the file with different names, together with a couple of batch files (e.g. `actionService1.bat` and `actionService2.bat`) to copy the appropriate file over your `APP` file.

Otherwise you might consider getting Windows versions of the Unix tools `sed` and `awk`, which excel at this type of file manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

The Batch file below assume that there is precisely one line with the target string. This method is relatively fast.

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "servername/ActionService.asmx,1" theFile.txt') do set lineNum=%%a
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" theFile.txt do (
   set "line=%%b"
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   if %%a equ %lineNum% (
      echo !line:1=0!
   ) else (
      echo(!line!
   )
   endlocal
)) > theFile.new
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: Way the first - suppresses emptylines
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (app) DO SET line=%%i&set line=!line:servername/ActionService.asmx,1=servername/ActionService.asmx,0!&ECHO(!line!
ECHO ====================
:: Way the second 
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('type app^|findstr /n "$"') DO (
  SET line=%%i
  set line=!line:servername/ActionService.asmx,1=servername/ActionService.asmx,0!
  SET line=!line:*:=!
  ECHO(!line!
)
ECHO ====================
GOTO :EOF
```

Two ways here. You would need to redirect your choice to a new file as you cannot update in-place.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a quick google search I found this http://www.dostips.com/?t=Batch.FindAndReplace

Answer (score 0):

Using a helper batch file called repl.bat from here: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

```
type app |repl "servername\/ActionService.asmx,1" "servername/ActionService.asmx,0" >appnew.txt
```